# How to write cleaner code

Tags: ios, model-view-controller

I'm facing problem while writing cleaner codes.

For example in one page, I need to load data from 5 api. I would write all the request code in ViewController.m file. That would make my file very messy. Can I write my request functions in other file and then call the function from ViewController.m?

Comment: Of course you can. Create a class called "APIManager" -for example- and add the networking functionality to it. You might want to make a "sharedInstance" for it (i.e as singleton pattern)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. Could you create an example for me please?

Comment: Here is one: https://github.com/MaxGaussDev/PMConnection that is a simple example of a connection manager class (this example is synchronous version, async would use delegates to communicate with viewcontrollers, but the principle is the same), you can put all your request urls in an NSArray in a similar way serverside routers handle them  etc.